# Inbound Change Set Error as :Code Coverage Failure

Tags: unit-test, change-set

Can any one help me out with this Error :
I have deployed the Visual force page and the controller .The outbound change set went successful. At Inbound change set I get an Error as :

> Code Coverage Failure
>       Your organization's code coverage is 71%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment.

Comment: did you upload a test class for the controller to go with this?  You need to cover some lines in your Visualforce controller with Apex tests,

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase code coverage on destination instance.

Answer (score 1):

When deploying on production, we need at least 75% overall coverage.
You will need to write Test class for your controller (to cover controller at least 75%). When deploying, include test class with controller and vf page.

Comment: :In DC it shows 80% overall coverage in sandbox when we move in to production it say it has only 71% overall coverage.